# running Objective-C application failed under Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, runtime-error

i cannot go more developing because i am unable to run my first application with shell, the .O files was generated but i don`t know how to run them (linking), the linking command that i use is :

```
gcc -o prog -Wno-import Student.o main.o -L c:/GNUstep/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include -lobjc
```

i got the famous `Id returned 1 exit status` output error
THX in advance for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading this and other questions, what are you trying to do?

It would appear that you are potentially trying to do some kind of school assignment that involves Objective-C, but are trying to use Windows.  That seems rather odd.

If you don't have access to a Mac, you'd have far, far, better luck using Linux (which is likely compatible with the computer you are running).

Comment: Agree. I've used a number of OS's and next to a Mac, my preference is for Linux as a developer platform.